# How do I import brightpi

Tags: python

I copied some Python code from the internet to work with the BrightPi IR light board. The first line is:

from brightpi import *

I get an error that there is no module named brightpi.

How do I find this module.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the file brightpi.py  to the same directory as your program.